How to use pandas read_fwf with japanese characters in data
I am trying to read data from text files that contain Japanese city names. Each line contains 32 bytes, with the name column being 22 bytes.
When I try to use pandas.read_fwf(), the results are wrong since pandas somehow counts the relevant Japanese characters as being 1 byte instead of 2.
Here is a working code snippet:
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_fwf(
    StringIO(
        """
7271熊本県天草・芦北地方      2K
2 43青森県三八上北地方        1K
3103新島・神津島近海         42K
2 48岩手県沿岸北部           17K
1 18北海道南西沖              2K
3 87茨城県南部               13K
2 50宮城県沖                  6K
7264有明海                    3K
7267橘湾                      2K
"""
    ),
    encoding="SHIFT-JIS",
    widths=[1, 3, 22, 5, 1],
    header=None,
)

the resulting dataframe is the following:
resulting dataframe
I would have thought the encoding would let pandas know how to handle things.
Is there a native pandas solution for this issue ?
I have read the entire read_fwf, read_csv and IO tools docs and searched far and wide SO questions here, here, here, here, here, and here but came up with nothing.
I would like to avoid building my own parser albeit it would be possible by reading by bytes and slicing.

I may be wrong, but when I check each line of your FWF data, I get different line lengths. From that point of view data is inconsistent.

The problem with your code is that you have the text as unicode strings in your code, and the lengths of the strings are of unequal length depending on the number of ideographs in line. If it is a shift-jis file, and you read it in as bytes, you'd have 33 bytes for most lines. So widths oyu are using are related to the shift-jis byte sequences.

@Andj yesterday I learned the difference between counting string characters and bytes in python. Each line is exactly 32 bytes (original data is 96 bytes).

What do you mean by original data is 96 bytes?

if i look at your sample data above, first line has 22 characters, second line has 23 characters, third line has 24 characters. last line has 30 characters.

if we take the last line "7267橘湾                      2K", discount the first four characters. and remove the last 6, that eaves us with 20 characters in the city name field. two ideographs and 18 spaces. looking at the first line. In the first line of data you gave, the city name field would take up 12 characters: ten CJK characters, and 2 spaces.

The the SHIFT-JIS data set was fixed width in terms of bytes, not characters.

You're passing StringIO, not BytesIO, so the string contains Unicode code points, not bytes. the encoding parameter isn't used. But even if you use BytesIO, encoding would turn it into code points, and you'd still have the same problem.
The following works, but isn't pretty.  I'm not a heavy user of Pandas so there might be a better option:
import io
import pandas as pd

# Display a dataframe with east asian characters better
pd.options.display.unicode.east_asian_width = True

# Grab the first 2 columns and the rest.
data = pd.read_fwf(
    io.StringIO(
        """
7271熊本県天草・芦北地方      2K
2 43青森県三八上北地方        1K
3103新島・神津島近海         42K
2 48岩手県沿岸北部           17K
1 18北海道南西沖              2K
3 87茨城県南部               13K
2 50宮城県沖                  6K
7264有明海                    3K
7267橘湾                      2K
"""
    ),
    widths=[1,3,100],
    header=None,
)

# Parse the 3rd column as a regular expression,
# matching the variable text, then the 5-width and 1-width fields.
data[[2,3,4]] = data[2].str.extract(r'(.*)(.{5})(.)', expand=True)
print(data)

Output.  It aligns correctly in a Windows command prompt, but slightly misaligned on SO (Chrome), but better than without the East Asian option:
   0    1                       2      3  4
0  7  271  熊本県天草・芦北地方        2  K
1  2   43  青森県三八上北地方          1  K
2  3  103  新島・神津島近海           42  K
3  2   48  岩手県沿岸北部             17  K
4  1   18  北海道南西沖                2  K
5  3   87  茨城県南部                 13  K
6  2   50  宮城県沖                    6  K
7  7  264  有明海                      3  K
8  7  267  橘湾                        2  K


Update:
Per OP's link in the comments to the original data, the code below processes the i2021.dat file from i2021.zip according to the data format and loads it in a dataframe:
import struct
import csv
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

# Process as fixed-width binary data...
with open(r'downloads\i2021.dat', 'rb') as infile:
    output = StringIO()  # Buffer intermediate CSV in memory
    writer = csv.writer(output)
    # Make a header 
    writer.writerow('type year month day hour min sec sec_se latdeg latmin lat_min_se londeg lonmin lon_min_se depth depth_se mag1 magt1 mag2 magt2 travel_time hypocenter_loc_perc sub_info max_int damage_class tsunami_class dist regnum regname numstat ident'.split())
    for line in infile:
        # I only bothered to parse type A lines:
        if line.startswith(b'A'):
            # parse fixed-width data as string fields
            data = list(struct.unpack('1s4s2s2s2s2s4s4s3s4s4s4s4s4s5s3s2s1s2s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s3s22s5s1sxx', line))
            # decode all fields so Japanese town names are readable
            data = [x.decode('shift-jis') for x in data]
            # buffer CSV rows
            writer.writerow(data)

output.seek(0)  # rewind in-memory file
df = pd.read_csv(output)  # Parse CSV data with pandas
print(df)

Output:
     type  year  month  day  hour  min   sec  ...  damage_class  tsunami_class  dist  regnum            regname  numstat  ident
0       A  2021      1    1     1   53  3610  ...                                  3     103     新島・神津島近海             42      K
1       A  2021      1    1     2   10  3773  ...                                  3     103     新島・神津島近海              1      K
2       A  2021      1    1     2   27   529  ...                                  3     103     新島・神津島近海              1      K
3       A  2021      1    1     3   17  3001  ...                                  3     103     新島・神津島近海              1      K
4       A  2021      1    1     3   41  2828  ...                                  3     103     新島・神津島近海              1      K
...   ...   ...    ...  ...   ...  ...   ...  ...           ...            ...   ...     ...                ...      ...    ...
2366    A  2021     12   30    17   45  3746  ...                                  7     293  宮古島近海                    4      K
2367    A  2021     12   31     4    2   716  ...                                  5     190   和歌山県北部                 13      K
2368    A  2021     12   31    14   52  4303  ...                                  4     135    石川県能登地方               23      K
2369    A  2021     12   31    23   17  2010  ...                                  2      48    岩手県内陸北部                1      K
2370    A  2021     12   31    23   23  3823  ...                                  7     296  種子島近海                    1      K

[2371 rows x 31 columns]

OP will still have to process columns, e.g., secs columns is a text string of F4.2 format (1234 == 12.34 seconds) but that is outside the question of how to process the fixed-width binary city name column.

"You're passing StringIO, not BytesIO, so the string contains Unicode code points" yes I am aware but I thought pandas would handle this transparently specifically in a fixed-width function. Thank you for the regex suggestion, but I am looking for a solution using the function pandas.read_fwf()

the actual data has 6M+ records and 96 bytes per record. I would like to avoid regex since it would be quite ugly and would probably opt for creating my own slicer if pandas can't handle it natively.
I'm not particularly attached to pandas, so if you know other tools I'm all ears

@blue Please provide the actual 96-byte data format then. Even the data provided, when saved as Shift-JIS-encoded, has 33 or 34 bytes per line (counting the newlines and depending on \r\n or \n line-endings.  Does the original data have newlines?  ([Edit] the question with complete information).

The rest of the original data doesn't matter since it's only numbers and English letters. The provided example fully reproduces the issue which is with the Japanese characters. The original data has \n newlines. For what it's worth, here's a link to the original data and it's format

@MarkTolonen I think the conplexity is that the data is not fixed width. It is fixed-width in terms of shift-jis bytes, but not characters. Each city name field seems to be padded with spaces to get the correct number of bytes, where spaces are single bytes.

@Andj I understand that the data is only fixed width in bytes. But it is not fixed width after decoding, hence the parsing solution I posted.

its also not fixed width in term of Shift-JIS characters. I assume the software that generated the data worked on bytes not characters.

@blue Per your link, I found it was easier to parse a file (I used i2021.dat) as bytes, decode each field as needed, and re-write the whole data file as a standard csv that pandas could use in <1s.  Don't worry about 6M+ records.  It doesn't take long.  I could post that code if you want.

@MarkTolonen thanks for the code update. Yes it appears working with bytes for parsing is the way to go. I hope I get the chance to test different codes and will let you know. It seems as far as my question about pandas being able to handle things, the answer is no, it cannot. Would it be a bother to reword slightly your answer to "no pandas cannot handle it natively because ... but here are some alternative ways" ?

@blue I think any solution has to deal with bytes because your spec says it is 22 bytes.  Pandas can handle it, but would need to parse the bytes, perhaps with an .apply(lambda ...), but would it be faster?  Does it matter when this solution works <1s?

New answer:
After rethinking the nature of the data, and that the data is fixed-width in terms of Shift-JIS bytes, but not in terms of characters, I'll update my answer or include a solution based on variable width lines.
The solution is based on the occurrence of specific fixed-width patterns within a variable width line, where one segment is variable length and remaining segments are fixed width. It splices each line based on the fixed width components, striping out whitespace, and creating a semicolon delimited CSV-like object that can be used by pd.read_cvs().
It assumes a character pattern of 1,3,*,5,1:
import pandas as pd
import io
pd.options.display.unicode.east_asian_width = True

data = []
with open('data_sjis.txt', 'r', encoding='shift-jis') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        line = line.strip()
        data.append(f"{line[0]};{line[1:4].strip()};{line[4:-6].strip()};{line[-6:-1].strip()};{line[-1]:}")

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("\n".join(data)), sep=";", header=None)

This gives:

I'll leave the original answer below:
Original answer:
An alternative approach is to read data in as binary data rather than as strings.
In the example below I have saved the example data as a Shift-JIS encoded text file. Read it in binary mode, and created a dataframe using a binary data stream.
import pandas as pd
import io

# Enable rendering of wide characters in terminal/console
pd.options.display.unicode.east_asian_width = True

# 1) Open Shift-JIS data in binary mode
with open('data_sjis.txt', 'rb') as fb:
    sjis_data = fb.read()

# 2) Read binary data with Shift-JIS encoding
df = pd.read_fwf(
    io.BytesIO(sjis_data),
    widths=[1, 3, 16, 10],
    header=None,
    encoding='shift-jis')

# display(df)
print(df)

The fiddly part is getting the widths right. When testing, your testing data should include both the longest city names, and the shortest city names, to determine the right width settings.
This gives:

Update to original answer:
If you want to divide the units in column 3 into a separate column, it will take fiddling with the widths, but I wasn't able to find a combination that would cleanly segment the data, The alternative is to split the column and then type cast column 3 to integers:
# Add divider between number and unit
df[3].replace(r'(\d+)K', r"\1-K", inplace=True, regex=True)

# split on divider creating a new column
df[[3, 4]] = df[3].str.split('-', expand=True)

# cast column 3 values to integer
df[3] = df[3].astype('int64')

Alternatively, convert all numbers to the same unit, then strip the unit.


I would assume there is no fiddly part about widths in fixed width formats. each record from the original data comes in 96 bytes and there is an explicit data format. There are 6M+ records so I would really like a native solution that correctly counts bytes. Thank you for the suggestions I appreciate them !

It is fixed width in Shift-JIS, each line is 32 bytes, 33 with \n. So yes fixed width. going on the fact  that every line in sgift-JIS is 32 bytes, and ideographs are 2 bytes, and other characetrs are one byte, I assume that there are a variable number of padding spaces with the ideographs to adjust each line to make 22 bytes. So at the boundary to pandas you no longer have fixed width. and the widths i used were the only ones I could find that did't loose data and leave NaN entries in dataframe. But those number may not work with the full dataset

To re-emphasis, it is fixed width in terms of the number of bytes in each line. This doesn't mean it is fixed width in terms of numbers of characters. each field has a very number of ideographs, ideographs are two bytes in shift-JIS, spaces are a single byte. each line is padded with additional spaces to make it fixed width to adjust for the number of ideographs. At least that's my understanding. Someone more familiar with legacy Japanese systems and software might be able to provide better detail.

@blue added a solution based on city name being varibale length, but will also work if city_name if fixed width. Assuming data is being read from file. If it's streamed it will need to be adjusted.

It seems there is no native way for pandas to handle fixed-byte-width data as compared to fixed-character-width data. The function pd.read_fwf assumes fixed-character-width data.
The only viable solution seems to be to develop a custom parser to split each line according to each columns byte width.
Here's the custom parser I developed using wcwidth. I haven't ran speed benchmarks on it yet.
The code is explained as a comment on each line:
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
from wcwidth import wcswidth
import numpy as np

widths = [1, 3, 22, 5, 1]
data = """
7271熊本県天草・芦北地方      2K
2 43青森県三八上北地方        1K
3103新島・神津島近海         42K
2 48岩手県沿岸北部           17K
1 18北海道南西沖              2K
3 87茨城県南部               13K
2 50宮城県沖                  6K
7264有明海                    3K
7267橘湾                      2K
"""


def parse_line(line: str, widths: list[int]) -> tuple[str]:
    # remove \n or \r characters
    stripped_line = line.strip()
    # skip empty lines
    if stripped_line == "":
        return None
    # get the theoretical cumulative sums of characters' widths
    cum_sum_split_widths = np.cumsum(widths)
    # get the actual line's cumulative sums of characters' widths
    cum_sum_widths = np.cumsum([wcswidth(item) for item in stripped_line])
    # use numpy.searchsorted to check where the theoretical splits should fall in the actual line
    sorter = cum_sum_widths.argsort()
    real_positions = sorter[
        np.searchsorted(cum_sum_widths, cum_sum_split_widths, sorter=sorter)
    ]
    # for each position where we need to split, append the characters so far to a list
    parsed_data = []
    start = 0
    for position in real_positions:
        parsed_data.append(stripped_line[start : position + 1].strip())
        start = position + 1
    # return list of the split characters
    return parsed_data

# use the above function for each line in the file to get a list of lists
with StringIO(data) as file:
    parsed_file = [
        parse_line(stripped, widths)
        for line in file.readlines()
        if (stripped := line.strip()) != ""
    ]
# use pandas to read the list of lists correctly
pd.DataFrame(parsed_file)

resulting dataframe
